# pure continuous analogue 96 Hertz signal

Tags: sound

I work with autistic children.  I need to produce a tactile input using pure analogue sound of 96 Hertz through a transducer.

The fifties  signal generator I got on e-bay does not put out enough signal strength to run the transducers. I need the signal to be pure analogue continuous and and the volume to be adjustable.

How do I generate a signal of 96Hz with a low source impedance?

Comment: It sounds like you just need a proper amplifier.

Comment: need more info about the transducer. is it a loudspeaker? impedance?

Comment: Why are you confined to analog techniques for tone generation?   For that matter, is there any evidence you need linear amplifier and cannot use a class-D one?  If such conclusions were reached, were they based on experiments with *good* implementations, or crude ones with obvious flaws?

Comment: Do you have more information upon the application / links etc? This is of interest to me. + I second that it just sounds to me you need an amp. For that frequency you could use a digital frequency gen chip or even an arduino with a specifically designed output frequency, or saying that even use our old friend the 555 to achieve 96Hz without a sig gen, then use any audio amp.

Comment: @Rendeverance the 555 or (unless done very carefully) Arduino are going to produce square waves.  These will sound notably different from a single frequency sinusoid.   But there are lots of ways of producing pure sinusoids.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that you charge and discharge a capacitor or the like, or using pwm with an appropriate rc filter (but the latter will need careful consideration) - saying that the signal from an AD9850 (commanded by an arduino or even something simpler - I believe it may be possible for it to remember its programmed frequency) will be exceptionally close

Comment: Is this a HP200CD? Thoroughly cool choice for this application. This has 600 Ohm output impedance but actually quite some power; what you want to drive anything non-600 Ohm is a transformer :) 160mW are louder than you think if they actually reach the speaker btw...

Comment: Mind that if the transducer is a piezo device with several kiloohms impedance, you need to be careful with your insulation especially if it is tactile - you could shock somebody....

Comment: Richard, has this been answered to your satisfaction, or is there more work to be done?  If you've gotten your answer, it helps all here if you'd tick it as accepted.

Comment: I suggest you look up the input impedance of your transducer and it's passband, also specify the power you need. Also PZT indeed a interesting choice.

Answer (score 1):

If your transducer has a similar impedance to an ordinary loudspeaker, then the answer would be to feed the output of your signal generator into any off-the-shelf audio power amplifier.  These are designed with a low-impedance output, for driving loudspeakers.

If the impedance of the transducer is particularly low (below about 8 ohms), then you may have to think a bit more about what to drive it with.

Comment: The transducer is :(nxt) Extreme 5w.  Part of the reason I need pure analogue is I've had complaint from the kids that they can sense directly the square rectangles that are used to form the digital packets - if you will- I can verify they are very sensitive beings...them...I'm still trying to figure out how to produce three and four dimensional coherent  analogue waves.  The old signal generators I’ve tried don't put out a strong signal to run the transducer I’m current playing with.

Comment: The complaint I get most is digital feels like saw blades.  I don't get the same complaints for analogue signals. Another complaint is lack of dimensionality in the waves propagated.  A simple analogue sign wave sounds tinny to

Comment: them...I'm still trying to figure out how to produce three and four dimensional coherent  analogue waves.  The old signal generators I’ve tried don't put out a strong signal to run the transducer I’m current playing with.

Comment: I get no complaints from 96 hrtz conventional weighted tuning forks...but I can't sustain a long enough tactile signal so they can be trained to locate and relax the muscles in their bodies....ie progressive relaxation.